# IIS 10 getting 401 unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, iis

Deploying an asp.net project on local IIS server as a release version. Getting 401 unauthorized error on API call (allow anonymous enabled). Server runs with administrator user principal. This principal has all the permissions. And the project declared as application with correct .net library. The only thing I can't change is read only flag on the project directory. Anyone can help? Nothing in google resources worked...

**Update: After a lot of searching and digging, I found a solution:**

1. **IIS Application basic settings** - The default settings is to run application with Application pool user, which is usually limited with it's files access permissions. So the idea is to run application with administrator user.
   Run as - enter administrator user name and password

   *Application pool type* - The default application pool type is 2 and sometimes new .NET libraries are not accessible. So you have to add all the missing ASP.NET types to IIS. 
   Usually ASP.Net version suppose to be classic, in this case application works fast. Otherwise application refresh time may take long period.
2. **Local folder permission**  - add local administrator, that you defined on IIS settings, and grand him all permissions to the folder recursively
3. **SQL Server Management**- the default server authentication is Windows Authentication, make it SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode
   Add new user to the server and grand him all the permission to the database
   Add this user to database Users and change the SQL connection string at the project accordingly. This way you prevent application pull trying to connect with database with it's user

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this here as I went around in circles trying to diagnose an intermittent 401 error.
I had a virtual sub directory within the web application that referenced an external folder which was out of the directory tree so had different folder permissions.
Any scripts that referenced this folder failed - while others ran completely fine.